# How to convert simple json object to csv using java?

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to convert the json object into a CSV file using java.

## My json :

```
{"Type":"Camera","modelName":"Alpha","asinno":"B0YUSAWZ"}
```

## Expected O/p:

```
Type,modelName,asinno
Camera,Alpha,B0YUSAWZ
```

I have tried using "CDL.toString()", but toString is expecting a json array but not a simple json object. How can we deal with simple json ?

Can anyone please help me out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON isn't really a (CSV) table format. So I guess you'll have to come up with something yourself. (If you don't already have,) you can gain Object-access to your JSON. You'll also need a CSVWriter. You can take the OpenCSV library or write a simple one yourself (that just concats the strings with commas inbetween).

Here is some logic

```
csvWriter = new CSVWriter(...)
json = parseJson(...)

//header line
for each key in json
    csvWriter.write(key)

csvWriter.nextLine()

//value line
for each key in json
    value = json[key]
    csvWriter.write(value)

csvString = csvWriter.asString()
```